# $\frac{\partial \coth ^{-1}(x)}{\partial x}$

Tags: calculus

I am asked to find

$\dfrac{d\coth ^{-1}(x)}{dx}$

I rewrite it to become

$x=\dfrac{1}{\tan(y)}$

$\dfrac{\text{dx}}{\text{dy}}=-\dfrac{1}{\frac{\sec ^2(x)}{\tan ^2(x)}}=-\sin^2(x)$

However the answer should be

$\dfrac{1}{1-x^2}$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For a start, you forgot the "h".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y=\operatorname{\coth}^{-1} x$. Note that $\operatorname{coth}^{-1}$ is the *inverse function* of $\operatorname{\coth}$. Thus we have 
$$x=\operatorname{coth}(y)=\frac{\cosh y}{\sinh y}.$$
Differentiating, we obtain
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{\sin^2 y-\cosh^2 y}{\sinh^2 y}=1-\operatorname{coth}^2 y=1-x^2.$$
Thus (when $\frac{dx}{dy}$ is defined, and non-zero), we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$.

Comment: I understand your result, but I thought that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[\operatorname{artanh}(x)]=\frac{1}{1-x^2}.$

Then why is it that $$ \operatorname{artanh}(x) \equiv \operatorname{arcoth}(x) \quad ?$$

Comment: The two functions differ by a constant.

Comment: How do you answer so quickly? Does your computer vibrate when a question is asked or something?

Comment: I had just finished a cup of strong coffee. Caffeine is good for speed. It is also good for endurance, makes the last few miles of a marathon easier.

Comment: @AndréNicolas What is the additive constant by which they differ?

Comment: Well, not quite an additive constant, because of the singularity. But they differ by $\pi/2$ some places, $-\pi/2$ others.

Comment: Could you expand the to the final answer as I am not sure if I get it

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the difference between $\coth^{-1}(x)$ and $1/\coth(x)$!
These are two different functions! Check with your textbook.

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$ \coth^{-1} x=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right), \mbox{for}\ |x|\gt 1$$
Then
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[\coth^{-1} x]=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)\right]$$
$$ =\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{d}{dx}[\ln(x+1)]-\frac{d}{dx}[\ln(x-1)]\right] $$
$$ =\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x-1}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{x-1-x-1}{(x+1)(x-1)}\right] $$
$$ =\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{-2}{x^2-1}\right]=-\frac{1}{x^2-1} =\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$